# (Processing) Creating second window makes the main very tiny

Tags: java, processing

Using processing 3.5 I am making second window. For no apparent (to me) the first window is messed up now. If I take out the settings and draw of the second the main window works just fine. Can anyone help diagnose this? (Ignore what my code is supposed to do)

```
  void setup(){
    size(300, 300);

    SecondApplet SA = new SecondApplet();
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[] {"DataWin"},SA);

  }

  void draw(){
    background(100, 45, 45);
  }

  public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

    void settings(){
      size(400, 500);
    }

    void draw(){
      background(100, 45, 100);
    }

  }
```

What's really funky is that if I comment out the declaration and running of SA it still has the first window tiny. But if you keep it and instead comment out the contents of `SecondApplet` it is the right size.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can copy and paste to see the problem?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem might be that your size becomes overriden when you draw the SecondApplet. Why not try the approach below?

```
  void setup(){

    FirstApplet Applet1 = new FirstApplet();
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[] {"DataWin1"},Applet1);

    SecondApplet Applet2 = new SecondApplet();
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[] {"DataWin2"},Applet2);

  }

  public class FirstApplet extends PApplet {

    void settings(){
      size(600, 600);
    }

    void draw(){
      background(100, 45, 45);
    }

  }

  public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

    void settings(){
      size(200, 200);
    }

    void draw(){
      background(100, 45, 100);
    }

  }
```

Have a global setup where you create your applet windows, and then have separate classes for each Window where you can define separate behaviour, for example.

[image]

Comment: Ah that sounds like a good idea, especially organizationally. I'll give it a try. Thanks!